# Flutter: Close DropdownButton (DropdownMenu)

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton, flutter-dropdownbutton

Is there a way to close the selection menu of a [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) containing all the DropdownMenuItems when an onTap function is executed (GestureDetector inside a DropdownMenuItem)?

Here is my implementation of the approach of Alperen Baskaya (in a slightly reduced version so that it is understandable). This approach however does not work yet and I am not sure whether it is because I have implemented it incorrectly or because the approach does not work for my problem.

```dart
class _BoatSelectionState extends State<BoatSelection> {
  FocusNode focusNode;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: 
            DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<Boat>(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: selectedBoat,
                onChanged: (Boat _boat) => Provider.of<BoatStreamsCubit>(context, listen: false).setBoat(_boat),
                selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return widget.boats.map<Widget>((Boat boat) {
                    return Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        BoatClassLogo(boat: boat),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: DesignValues.paddingMd),
                            child: BoatInformation(boat: boat),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList();
                },
                items: widget.boats.map<DropdownMenuItem<Boat>>((Boat _boat) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Boat>(
                    value: _boat,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: DesignValues.paddingMd),
                          child: BoatClassLogo(boat: _boat),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: BoatInformation(boat: _boat),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            focusNode.unfocus();
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoatForm(CreationState.edit, _boat)));
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.edit,
                              color: AppColors.primary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I looked up the internal implementation of DropdownMenu in dart.

The popover for DropdownMenu is created by using `Navigator.push()`. It waits for the user to click an item and returns the value with `Navigator.pop()`. So we can pop the popover manually by getting the dropdown's context via a `GlobalKey`.

```
late GlobalKey dropdownKey;  

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropdownKey = GlobalKey();
}
```

...

```
DropdownButton<Boat>(
    key: dropdownKey,
    ...)
```

And remove it using `Navigator.pop()`

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(dropdownKey.currentContext);
```

Full code:

```
class _BoatSelectionState extends State<BoatSelection> {
  GlobalKey dropdownKey;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropdownKey = GlobalKey(); // Init GlobalKey, allows to close the DropdownButton
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: 
            DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<Boat>(
                key: dropdownKey,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: selectedBoat,
                onChanged: (Boat _boat) => Provider.of<BoatStreamsCubit>(context, listen: false).setBoat(_boat),
                selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return widget.boats.map<Widget>((Boat boat) {
                    return Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        BoatClassLogo(boat: boat),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: DesignValues.paddingMd),
                            child: BoatInformation(boat: boat),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList();
                },
                items: widget.boats.map<DropdownMenuItem<Boat>>((Boat _boat) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Boat>(
                    value: _boat,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: DesignValues.paddingMd),
                          child: BoatClassLogo(boat: _boat),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: BoatInformation(boat: _boat),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(dropdownKey.currentContext); // Closes the dropdown
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoatForm(CreationState.edit, _boat)));
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.edit,
                              color: AppColors.primary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way of doing it in a stateless widget?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you can use focus node for dropdown menu.

```
FocusNode dropdown;
```

Initializing in initstate is needed;

```
dropdown = FocusNode();

child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                         child: DropdownButton <String>(
                            focusNode: dropdown,
```

Then when you may think to close this menu execute in ontap;

```
  dropdown.unfocus();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In itself the suggestion looks promising, but unfortunately unfocus() has no effect and does not change my problem. Here is my implementation in a slightly reduced version so that it is understandable: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yH1a9SSm). Did I do something wrong in the implementation or does the approach not work?

Comment: I cannot see what you pasted under pastbin link. When I use unfocus function the dropdown list disappears. But you can use setState() in onTap function to build your main widget again. It may help. If you paste your code I can see properly what error is

Comment: have you tried wrapping unfocus and navigator with setState?

Comment: `setState(() {
  focusNode.unfocus();
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => BoatForm(CreationState.edit, _boat),
    ),
  );
});` 
This unfortunately doesn't change anything.