# How to close all openable widgets when i click and open one of them?

Tags: flutter

i have a listview builder . i have custom widget (like dropdown) for show in listview. i need to close all widgets when i click another one. i mean in all list only one widget can be open. can anybody help me?

```
 return Column(
  children: [
    InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isHide = !isHide;
            if (isHide) {
              height = 0;
            } else {
              height = 10;
            }
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TextWidget(
                    text: this.widget.title,
                    size: 15,
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  
                  
                  height < 1
                      ? Container(
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            height: height,
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1),
                            child: TextWidget(
                              text: this.widget.mainText,
                              textColor: Colors.grey,
                              size: 10,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(
                          height: 100,
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            height: height,
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1),
                            child: TextWidget(
                              overfloww: TextOverflow.fade,
                              text: this.widget.subText,
                              textColor: Colors.grey,
                              size: 15,
                            ),
```

this is my custom widget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Close DropdownButton (DropdownMenu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439716/flutter-close-dropdownbutton-dropdownmenu)

Comment: similar. but i need to close past widget when i click new one

Comment: i can handle index. bu i cant find how to change a spesific widget with index